# Which chemicals are most responsible for the blue sky?

Tags: atmosphere, atmospheric-optics

Earth's atmosphere is especially good at refracting blue light, which makes the sky blue.

Which gas or gasses is/are responsible for this?

If some gasses in the atmosphere do not refract blue light, what colors DO they refract?

Is it possible to have a breathable atmosphere with a non-blue sky?

Comment: please take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering you have multiple questions here please edit your question so it focuses on only one of them.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "molecular nitrogen" since it is the majority of our atmosphere.  But, calling this refraction is incorrect IMO; it should be called scattered light.